# SPA architecture to enable features or component based on account permissions?

Tags: laravel, security, vue.js, single-page-application

I’m going to build an online photo editor - Single Page Application with Vue.js + Laravel (beginner in both frameworks).

How can I disable or limit some features if user account is free, and enable that if account is premium?

For example: if I want some tools like Color picker is only available to paid user, how can I do that securely?

( Vue is frontend so I’m afraid that if the logic stand totally in javascript, user with enough knowledge can modify it by dev tools to enable paid feature )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [Laratrust](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust). It's a fantastic package for creating roles and permissions in Laravel.

Vue is indeed the frontend, but your application's logic is still performed in PHP, via Laravel. Your controllers will determine what a user's permissions are and return the appropriate data/error accordingly. There's a lot to describe here but there's tons of great resources that do it.

Rather than describing how Vue and Laravel work together, I'd point you towards [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/). You can learn A LOT there off just the free videos alone, well worth the money though.

https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/26

https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/27